# How to modify rendered image before displaying it in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, rendering, augmented-reality

I would like to render a scene in Unity. After that i'd like to applay some changes (shift and rotations) to the rendered image before displaying it to the user screen.

Iis there a way to do it in Unity?

Thanks

I see there is a OnPostRender method in Unity, but I can't understand if it could be exploited for my objectives.

Comment: have it on a second camera, that grabs an image, you then do whatever, display it on the main one?

Comment: You could set up your camera to render to a [RenderTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html). Then you can manipulate this texture how you like before rendering it to screen...

Comment: @asj so i can set my main camera as RenderTexture, I render the scene and then i can manipulate the image. Do you know any guide to do that? And after that how can I display the final image on the screen?

Comment: You can use [OnRenderImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html).

Comment: @shingo unfortunately with srp it does not work!

Comment: What does srp mean? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Scriptable Render Pipeline. It seems it does not support that method...

Answer (score 0):

You basically need two cameras in your scene. The first camera has a [RenderTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html) set as the output target. Then you do your manipulations of any sort directly on this render texture.

In your scene you also need a quad which *Texture* field is set to your *RenderTexture*.

Your second ("normal") camera then just renders this quad with the attached, manipulated *RenderTexture*.

Here's a short [guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@16.0/manual/rendering-to-a-render-texture.html) on this topic. But Google is your friend here, this was done many times before.

Comment: no you don't really ...

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Id argue maybe not need but can do it that way, its certainly the way that comes to mind for me without having needed to do it, but much like having a minimap etc it is a way to do it

Comment: I am new in Unity. My final goal is to reproduce in real time some movements, that is way i want to move the image after the render (just to position the image in real time). Which approach would you suggest?

Comment: so just move it, it will render when moved.. I think maybe you need to explain what you need to achieve not what you think you need to do

Comment: Yeah - maybe I've misunderstood your question.
If you need to manipulate a **already rendered** image in any way, the answer above would be a proper solution.
If you need to manipulate _GameObjects_ and other scene stuff, you need to do this **before** rendering a frame.
What exactly do you mean with "position the image in real time" ?

Comment: Basically I am in Augmented Reality setup, I have some sensors which give me the position in the world of the user, since the rendering requires time my idea is to render the image using the information at that time, after the rendering, that is slow, the position given by the sensors is changed. By shifting/rotating the already rendered image I can "correct" it. I am trying to implement time (or image) warp. In general I would find a way to get the already rendered image, manipulate it (it  dont know how) and then display it to the user

Comment: what rendered image, you mean the items from unity? if so, you need to profile and determine what makes them "slow"

Comment: Since I am in AR setting I need to display, on some glasses many holograms. A Unity camera moves according to the head of the user, records whats the user should see, and project it on the glasses. Since the whole process (and so the rendering) is slow i need to compensate for the delay. Here at page 208 you find what I mean http://lavalle.pl/vr/vrbook.pdf

Comment: @Luca theoretically you could use the setup from the answer above to implement a time warp (_Post-rendering image warp_) functionality like described in the publication you linked. however you would probably need not only two cameras, but also two render textures. one with a higher resolution to shift into the warped texture with a smaller resolution.

Comment: Is the rendering of the two cameras uncorrelated? I mean, after rendering with the first camera can i "move" the second one before its rendering?

Comment: absolutely, you could do that too! however, I would assume that editing the texture is more performant.